# LIMIT does not contain variables

Tags: sql, postgresql, function

Variable in the LIMIT clause is working for a normal input paarmeter but not working when the parameter is a table type or json

**Table Types:**

```
create type tt_input as (id integer, batchsize integer);
create type tt_input as (id integer,name character varying);
```

**Working in this case:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sample_function(
    id integer,
    batchsize integer)
    RETURNS SETOF tt_output
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'

    COST 100
    VOLATILE 
    ROWS 1000
    
AS $BODY$  
DECLARE
        p_id alias for $1;
        p_batchsize alias for $2;
    
BEGIN 

    return query (select t.id, t.name from sample_table t 
                        where t.id =p_id 
                        limit (p_batchsize));
END
$BODY$;
```

**Not Working in this case:** throwing error -  variables in LIMIT should not....

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sample_function(
    tt_input text)
    RETURNS SETOF tt_output
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'

    COST 100
    VOLATILE 
    ROWS 1000
    
AS $BODY$  
    
    
BEGIN 

    return query (select t.id, t.name from sample_table t 
                        inner join json_populate_recordset(null::tt_input ,tt_input::json) as r
                        on t.id =r.id 
                        limit (r.batchsize));
END
$BODY$;
```

Comment: Sorry, what you try to achieve by this function? How you imagine variable limits for single select ...

Comment: Just want to limit the number of records. But my limit input is in a table type attribute

Comment: @SayanB there's no "just' here. The batch size isn't known until the query runs and produces results. Even then, the actual batch size would vary from one row to the next.

Comment: Did you try to use `tt_input` pass arbitrary parameters to the stored procedure? That defeats the purpose of using a stored procedure in the first place

Comment: @SayanB if you make that a SQL grammar teacher - what you try to do makes no sense as a relational query. `r.batchsize` depends on the query result when `LIMIT` is meant to *restrict* that result. `batchsize` has *multiple* values too, which means the server would have to pick an arbitrary value to restrict the results. The values returned by `batchsize` are affected by ... `LIMIT` though. So if what you want was allowed, `LIMIT(r.batchsize)` could end up changing what the LIMIT is

Comment: Let's clarify this. you provide json parameter `tt_input`, for example `[{id:1, batchsize:5},{id:2, batchsize:10},]` convert it to records, join to table, it's OK, but how many records you want to receive and and of function? 5? 10? ...

Comment: What you can do is use a ranking function like `ROW_NUMBER()` to calculate the rank of each row and compare it with another column value in `WHERE`. You may have to use CTEs to calculate the rank as most databases don't like ranking functions in `WHERE` to avoid unpredictable results and infinite recursions

Comment: @SlavaRozhnev I understand where you are going ! Its like I want 5 records for 1st set, 10 for 2nd. Put all the things in a temp table. Return all 15.

Comment: Ok, understand, I just need to use a loop. This will work.

Answer (score 0):

> Variable in the LIMIT clause is working for a normal input parameter but not working when the parameter is a table type or json.

It's true. You Can't Do That™, unfortunately.

Comment: Thats what I am thinking, how do I achieve this, because my limit inputs are there in a table type attribute.